# What can I do with my pension when leaving Norway?

Tags: pension, norway

I'm returning to Sri Lanka, after working in Norway for 2.5 years. Wondering what options I have in taking the pension accumulated.

Comment: Commenting because I really don't know, but this might be helpful with research: In the UK, there's QROPS if you deal with international pensions. A similar scheme probably exists in Norway.

Comment: Many countries actually have pension treaties to avoid having to deal with these issues (Norway has them with some countries, but I assume Sri Lanka may not be one of them). If you return to a country that has a treaty, then you can claim the time overseas for your pension in your home country (as I said this may not be applicable to you).

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be out of luck!

If you have worked in Norway, you are only able to get your pension once you reach retirement age (67) if you have worked in Norway for **more than 3 years**. This [webpage from the University of Oslo](http://www.uio.no/english/for-employees/employment/international-researchers/stay/pension/) for its international employees explains this:

> 3 years of employment is required to get a pension from the Norwegian Public Service Pension Fund and the National Pension Fund (one year for EEA-citizens)

And under the *What happens when you leave* section:

> - Pension contributions can not be transferred to any other pension fund or refunded to contributers moving abroad.
> - Contributions will only be paid out when the contributor reaches retirement age according to Norwegian law.

So even if you worked there for 3 years, you could not get the money refunded, but would have to wait until you reach retirement age and then contact the Norwegian authorities to claim your pension.

Comment: So the majority of people on short term contracts will never access their contributions to Norway's pension fund. It discriminates against foreigners who will lose the time to save for their retirement while they work in Norway. What a scam.

Comment: @discombobulated Not sure what it is called in Norway, but in Germany it is not a **contribution** fund, but more a **solidarity** fund for pensions. The employed of today finance the pensions of today. Your pension of tomorrow will be financed by the employed of tomorrow. This is different from private pension schemes where your final pension is based on the (possible) returns of your contributions over the years.

Comment: I assume this is a long time away for you… But you might enquire if it is possible to pay voluntarily the missing six months at a minimum rate, which might be cheap enough and give you a reasonable amount of money every month when you are 67.